# how do the customize android app send message to the official WeChat app?

Tags: android, message, wechat

second question, what is the WeChat app's package name? (due to i can't find it)

follow main quesition, i use WeChat official android sample code to execute the app.
But i don't know how to assign the specific WeChat user with sending out message .
any friend tell me how to finish it?

this is WeChat Sample code for sening message:
http://dev.wechat.com/download/sdk/WeChat_SDK_sample_android_en.zip

```
  public static final String APP_ID = "wxd930ea5d5a258f4f";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
api = WXAPIFactory.createWXAPI(this, Constants.APP_ID);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
WXTextObject textObj = new WXTextObject();
                        textObj.text = text;
WXMediaMessage msg = new WXMediaMessage();
                   msg.mediaObject = textObj;
                               msg.description = text;
SendMessageToWX.Req req = new SendMessageToWX.Req();
                         req.transaction = buildTransaction("text"); 
                     req.message = msg;
                     req.scene = isTimelineCb.isChecked() ? SendMessageToWX.Req.WXSceneTimeline : SendMessageToWX.Req.WXSceneSession;
                        api.sendReq(req);
                        finish();
}
```

---

1. A.how can i know that i should send who?
2. B.APP_ID = "wxd930ea5d5a258f4f" represent is WeChat chat id?
3. C.i just run the sample app,then i send out message .it say"發送被拒絕"
   that mean refuse to send message.what is the problem?
4. D.i live in Taiwan,When i register  to http://dev.wechat.com/signup 
   . i input my Taiwan format phone code,but my phone never receive any
   WeChat verification code for SMS

In result, i just want to know that how could the custom android app send message to the specific Wechat.Use the sample code to achieve the goal?

Comment: package name `com.tencent.mm`

Comment: plz write down more information about what you want to do